# I have a file organiser powershell script which runs without any error but it doesnt perform the moving operation

Tags: powershell, scripting

It is a file organiser script I wrote for myself. For a specific purpose of mine. Whenever I try to run it It runs and closes off. But the move operation is not happening. The below comments may help you understand what the code is doing.Please help me on what am i doing wrong here. I am extremely new to Powershell Scripting.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser

# Global variable declarations
$global:pathsFromConfig = Get-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot"\MoverPaths.txt"
$global:categoriesFromConfig = Get-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot"\MoverCategories.txt"
$global:categryHash = @{}

# Method call to read configs, create dirs, & move files
readCreateAndMoveFiles

# Method definition
function readCreateAndMoveFiles{
    # Reads categories config.txt and splits them line by line
    # Adds each line as a key value pair to a hashtable
    foreach($category in $categoriesFromConfig)
    {
        $temp = $category -split ":"  
        $categryHash.add($temp[0].trim().toString(),($temp[1]).trim().toString())
    }

    # For each category in the hash table, calls create directory method, and then moves the files based on current category

    foreach($hashItem in $categryHash.GetEnumerator()){
        # Creates a directory with the Hash Key
        Foreach($pathToMonitor in $pathsFromConfig){
            $categoryFullPath = $pathToMonitor+$hashItem.Name
            createDirectory($categoryFullPath)

            # Moves files into that directory 
            Set-Location -Path $pathToMonitor
            $extentions = $hashItem.Value
            Get-Item $extentions | Move-Item -Destination $categoryFullPath
            $categoryFullPath = ""
        }
    }
}
        
# Method Definition
function createDirectory ($categoryName)
{
    if(Test-Path -Path $categoryName)
    {
        # Directory already Exists!
    }
    else
    {
        # Creates Directory
        md $categoryName
    }
}
```

The config files are hereby:

**MoverCategories.txt**
`Images:*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.png,*.tiff,*.raw,*.heic,*.gif,*.svg,*.eps,*.ico`
`Documents:*.txt,*.pdf,*.doc,*.docx,*.xls,*.xlsx,*.ppt,*.pptx,*.html,*.xls,*.csv,*.rtx`

**MoverPaths.txt**

```
D:\Downloads\
```

Comment: For one thing, move line `readCreateAndMoveFiles` to **below** the function definitions, otherwise you call on them before they are known to the script

Comment: Ohh, Is it? Silly me i thought functions are defined at the bottom. Let me try it out once. Thanks Theo.

Comment: Unfortunately, It didnt help either The files are still sitting there

Comment: @surya To troubleshoot, can you add `Write-Host "moving $extentions to $categoryFullPath"` inside of your `foreach` loop? Then run and check the console output to see the issue.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale or `-WhatIf`

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I checked the values using debugger on Powershell ISE as well as Visual Studio. The values are correct. It is just that i feel that command is not executing correctly.

Comment: I have found out the issue:


**Expected:**
`Get-Item *.jpg,*.jpeg,*.png,*.tiff,*.raw,*.heic,*.gif,*.svg,*.eps,*.ico | Move-Item -Destination $categoryFullPath`


**Current Value:**
`Get-Item "*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.png,*.tiff,*.raw,*.heic,*.gif,*.svg,*.eps,*.ico" | Move-Item -Destination $categoryFullPath`


**Actual code:**
`Get-Item $extentions | Move-Item -Destination $categoryFullPath`


since `$extentions` is a string it is failing. It needs to be some other type. Could someone help me achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to do this. Thanks for all of your input. Now the script moves files. Instead of sending all extentions in a single shot, i made it into an array and sent it one by one. Now it works fine. If you guys could help me reduce the time of execution that would be great.But the code works now I am happy.

```
foreach($hashItem in $categryHash.GetEnumerator()){
    # Creates a directory with the Hash Key
    Foreach($pathToMonitor in $pathsFromConfig){
        $categoryFullPath = $pathToMonitor+$hashItem.Name
        createDirectory($categoryFullPath)
        # Moves files into that directory 
        [String[]]$extentions = @()
        $extentions = $hashItem.Value -split ','
        foreach($string in $extentions)
        {
            Get-Item $pathToMonitor\* -Include $string | Move-Item -Destination $categoryFullPath
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#specify path(s)
$path = "$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads"

## this is make an array of the extensions in the foloder
$extensions = Get-ChildItem -Path $path  | Select-Object -Unique  -Property @{label = 'ext'
  expression                                                                        = { $_.Extension.substring(1) }
}

## this function will 
function New-FoldersByName {
  param
  (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, HelpMessage = 'Data to process')]
    $InputObject
  )
  process { 
    Set-Location $path
    if (!(Test-Path -PathType Container $InputObject )) {

      New-Item -ItemType directory -Name $InputObject.ext -WhatIf
      Write-Host -Message "A folder named $($InputObject.ext) does not exist. Creating..."
    }
    else {
      Write-Host -Message "A folder named $($InputObject.ext) already exists. Skipping..."
    }
  }
}



##this is a reuseable function to moves items in a folder into a subfolder named after the files extension
## if extension is .exe the file with be moved to ./EXE/filename.exe

function Move-ItemsByName {
  param
  (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, HelpMessage = 'Data to process')]
    $InputObject
  )
  process {
    Set-Location -Path $path
    Move-Item -Path ('*.{0}' -f $InputObject.ext) -Destination ('{0}' -f $InputObject.ext) -WhatIf
  }
}

$extensions | New-FoldersByName
$extensions | Move-ItemsByName
```

Comment: I have the config files for parth and extensions. The path config is to add multiple folders at a later point in time if needed. Rather hardcoding the path. Extentions with categories will define which type of files goes where. 

But your code seems interesting. I’ll try to modify mine with this input. In the meanwhile could you let me know if the same is happening here? I am still trying to understand the code logic. Please correct me if i am wrong.